# Can we mention array size at run time?

Tags: java, arrays

As per my understanding we need to define the array size at compile time. But as per below code, it seems that we can provide the array size at run time also.

```
public class Test { 

    public static void main(String args[]){ 

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int length= scan.nextInt();

        int arr[] = new int[length];

        for(int i =0; i < length;i++){
            arr[i]=i;
        }
        for(int data : arr){
            System.out.println("Data: "+data);
        }

    }
}
```

I really appreciate if someone can please explain me the behaviour.

Comment: Not sure what there is to explain. Your understanding was/is incorrect.

Comment: It's not that you define it at compile time, it's that it is defined at some point. In the case you see above, when the code is executed and it creates the `arr[]` variable, it will define the size then. The array is then fixed to that size, but you don't have to hard code the size in prior to being created.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass anything of type `int` to the `new T[<int>]` constructor, for example you can also do this:

```
int userInput = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
int len = 12 + 14 * 3 / userInput;
byte[] arr = new byte[len];
// arr has now the size as specified by len.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can of it like this - 
  your program really doesn't mind what you write in that box (as long as its a reasonable number for the array data structure - less than Integer.MAX_VALUE and non-negative) until it starts to run it.
So if you write

```
int[] box = new int[4];
```

Java doesn't know before you build it that the array's length will be 4. In fact, until the code is run, the array isn't even initialized.

In that case, it makes sense that you can use variables for array lengths, as long as when the program goes to run that line of code, the variable is a reasonable number for array lengths.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can create an Array with its size to be determined at runtime.

From your code:

```
int arr[] = new int[length];
```

when this line is reached during runtime, the program allocates an array of integers that its size is equals to the current value of the variable `length` and reference to it by `arr`